# Как упорядочить элементы в меню сайта

Tags: html, css, классы, menu, header

Хочу сделать две ссылки в меню слева, две ссылки справа, а по центру логотип, размер которого может вылазить за блок, не изменяя размеров блока, как на [этом сайте](https://dotahouse.wtf/).
Было сначала так, всё работало, но логотип изменял размеры блока, и не вылазил за него:

```css
/* Container */
.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width:800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  
  /* Header */
.header {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.header__inner {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}

/* Nav */
.nav {
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 55px;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: black;

    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.nav__link1 {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;

    color: green;
    text-decoration: none;

    background-color: black;

    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    border-left: 2px solid red;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;

    padding: 0px 30px;
    height: 55px;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.nav__link2 {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;

    color: green;
    text-decoration: none;

    background-color: black;

    border-bottom: 2px solid red;

    padding: 0px 26px;
    height: 55px;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;

    color: green;
    text-decoration: none;

    background-color: black;

    border-bottom: 2px solid red;

    padding: 0px 26px;
    height: 55px;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.nav__link3 {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;

    color: green;
    text-decoration: none;

    background-color: black;

    border-bottom: 2px solid red;

    padding: 0px 26px;
    height: 55px;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.nav__link4 {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;

    color: green;
    text-decoration: none;

    background-color: black;

    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    border-right: 2px solid red;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;

    padding: 0px 26px;
    height: 55px;
    line-height: 50px;
  }
```

```html
<header class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header__inner">
                <nav class="nav">
                    <a class="nav__link1" href="#">П</a>
                    <a class="nav__link2" href="#">F</a>
                    <img src="../logo.png" class="logo" alt="Logo" title="logo" />
                    <a class="nav__link3" href="#">К</a>
                    <a class="nav__link4" href="#">П</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Потом попробовал вот так, и вообще всё сломал:

```css
/* Container */
.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width:800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Header */
.header {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.header__inner {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}

/* Nav */
.nav {
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 55px;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: black;

    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.nav_left {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
}

.nav_right {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
}

.nav__link1 {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;

    color: green;
    text-decoration: none;

    background-color: black;

    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    border-left: 2px solid red;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;

    padding: 0px 30px;
    height: 55px;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.nav__link2 {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;

    color: green;
    text-decoration: none;

    background-color: black;

    border-bottom: 2px solid red;

    padding: 0px 26px;
    height: 55px;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;

    color: green;
    text-decoration: none;

    background-color: black;

    border-bottom: 2px solid red;

    padding: 0px 26px;
    height: 55px;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.nav__link3 {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;

    color: green;
    text-decoration: none;

    background-color: black;

    border-bottom: 2px solid red;

    padding: 0px 26px;
    height: 55px;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.nav__link4 {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;

    color: green;
    text-decoration: none;

    background-color: black;

    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    border-right: 2px solid red;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;

    padding: 0px 26px;
    height: 55px;
    line-height: 50px;
  }
```

```html
<header class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header__inner">
                <nav class="nav">
                    <div class="nav__left">
                        <a class="nav__link1" href="#">П</a>
                        <a class="nav__link2" href="#">F</a>
                    </div>
                    <img src="../logo.png" class="logo" height="300px" alt="Logo" title="logo" />
                    <div class="nav__right">
                        <a class="nav__link3" href="#">К</a>
                        <a class="nav__link4" href="#">П</a>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Может где-то чего-то лишнего написал... Запутался... Помогите, буду благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
/* Container */

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}


/* Header */

.header {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.header__inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}


/* Nav */

.nav {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 55px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: black;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.nav__link1 {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  color: green;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  border-left: 2px solid red;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  padding: 0px 30px;
  height: 55px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.nav__link2 {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  color: green;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  padding: 0px 26px;
  height: 55px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.logo_container {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  color: green;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  padding: 0;
  width: 140px;
  height: 55px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: -5px;
  height: 160px;
}

.logo img {
  height: 160px;
}

.nav__link3 {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  color: green;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  padding: 0px 26px;
  height: 55px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.nav__link4 {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  color: green;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  border-right: 2px solid red;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  padding: 0px 26px;
  height: 55px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header__inner">
      <nav class="nav">
        <a class="nav__link1" href="#">П</a>
        <a class="nav__link2" href="#">F</a>
        <div class="logo_container">
          <div class="logo"><img src="https://clipart-best.com/img/clown/clown-clip-art-56.png" alt="Logo" title="logo" /></div>
        </div>
        <a class="nav__link3" href="#">К</a>
        <a class="nav__link4" href="#">П</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: То, что нужно! Спасибо большое!